# How to fix "single sub-query returns multiple rows"

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a problem to execute this query in oracle apex. Please help me how to fix it. The query will update multiple rows in the table using loop.
 begin

```
UPDATE app
SET APPFLG = 'A',
APRVBY=:app_user
WHERE ACTNUM = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row) and APPFLG = 'N';

IF SQL%NOTFOUND
THEN
    raise_application_error (
        -20001,
        'Unable to Update Customer :' || APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row));
    ROLLBACK;
    RETURN;
ELSE
    UPDATE aas
    SET opndat = (select opndat from app where actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row)),
        SANAD1 = (select SANAD1N from app where actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row)),
        CRIRTE = (select CRIRTEN from app where actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row)),
        DNPAMT = (select DNPAMTN from app where actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row)),

    WHERE BRANCD = :AI_BRANCH_CODE AND actype = 'C88' and actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row);

    for i in (select ACTNUM, CERTNO, CURVAL, SECSTS from sd_app where actnum= APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row))
    loop
        update sd
        set ACTNUM =  i.ACTNUM,
            CERTNO = i.CERTNO, 
            CURVAL = i.CURVAL, 
            SECSTS =  i.SECSTS 
        where BRANCD = :AI_BRANCH_CODE AND actype = 'C88' and actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row);                    
    end loop ;              
END IF;
```

The actual result can update the sd table.

Comment: It appears that the error is coming from the update of `aas`, because `app` has multiple rows which match `actnum = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03 (v_row)`. Either that shouldn't be true and your data needs to be fixed; or you need another condition to isolate a single row; or you need some other way to decide which of the matching rows to use.

Comment: sd_app table has multiple records of data where actnum is same. so it creates error in the executing loop. How to can i execute loop for multiple row of same actnum num? @AlexPoole

Comment: You already have a loop for `sd_app`, I'm talking about the `update aas` statement - which has the subqueries that can throw the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole . aas table returns multiple data. I add a condition into where clause and it returns my expected result.